# Is downvoting perfectly anonymous?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, reputation-history, anonymous

When I was checking someone's profile, I came to know that I can see his reputation history too with the time of that activity. Now, suppose if I get a downvote and I suspect someone for this, so if I check his reputation history, I must see a -1 on his reputation at the same time when I got the downvote.

Does this make downvoting non-anonymous?

Comment: In addition to the answer by Patrick Hofman - keep in mind that the -1 is only for answers. Downvotes on questions are free.

Comment: -1 rep difference is too little to spot. [Spotting -30 is easy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9pz5.png) :)

Comment: No; Just because a user's reputation decreases by 1 point DOES NOt mean they downvoted your contribution .  Stop worrying about downvotes it takes 5 downvotes to counter a single upvote.  If your getting downvotes your contribution has a problem that should be solved not ignored

Comment: I guess that's why I shouldn't have commented after downvoting :/

Comment: @Won't I think it depends on the question. Partivularly on the SO happens quite often, that a question has 3-5 answers, all of them bad and utilizes a common misconception. In these cases, if I am really sure, then I vote all down and explain the reason for all OPs in comments. Yes, they aren't happy, but they can't really do anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> so if I check his reputation history, I must see a -1 on his reputation at the same time when I got downvote.

The Stack Exchange developers have been smart enough to acknowledge that easy way to see user's voting patterns, so downvotes mentioned on your profile are only visible to you, not to other users.

There are other ways though to try to find who voted on you, but you can't say for sure who voted. So yes, voting is anonymous. Perfectly: no.