# Should we do something about the [anonymous] and [anonymous-visitors] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request

On Meta Stack Exchange, there are two tags, [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) and [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors). These two tags are synonyms since the tag wiki of [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) says:

> This tag is for questions regarding anonymous users.

The [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) tag says:

> This tag is for questions about the anonymous users, i.e. users who haven't registered on the Stack Exchange site or browsing it anonymously (not logged in).

I think that we should keep [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) because although it's less popular than [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous), its name is less ambiguous. I've seen several cases where [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) was used in questions about the fact that voting is anonymous that have nothing to do with anonymous users. Here are a few examples:

- [Is downvoting perfectly anonymous?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292847/349538)
- [Anonymity of downvotes has a loophole](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133433/349538)
- [Communicate with Anonymous Voters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89580/349538)

I therefore suggest that all questions about anonymous users that are tagged [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) should be retagged to [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) (I personally think that it would have been better to call it [anonymous-users](/questions/tagged/anonymous-users) but since we already have [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) we might as well use it). The [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) tag could be made a synonym of [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors) or simply burninated. If [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) becomes a synonym of [anonymous-visitors](/questions/tagged/anonymous-visitors), questions tagged [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) that aren't about anonymous users could be retagged manually (this shouldn't be too difficult since [anonymous](/questions/tagged/anonymous) only has 84 questions).